# overloading * to act as dereference

Tags: c++

I'm having a difficult time trying to overload the * operator. I am attempting to use it in order to dereference a pointer. I've posted what I'm currently using to attempt this. Now when I try to use it I get the following error `indirection requires pointer operand ('Iterator' invalid)`

**//Usage**

```
Iterator List::Search(int key) {
    Iterator temp(head);

    while (!temp.isNull()) {
        if (*temp == key) {
            //return temp;
            cout << *temp << endl;
        }
        temp++;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

**//Header File**

```
class Iterator {
public:
    Iterator &operator *(const Iterator &) const;
private:
    node* pntr;
};
```

**//CPP File**

```
Iterator &Iterator::operator *(const Iterator & temp) const {
    return temp.pntr;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The unary de-rerefence operator doesn't need a parameter. It is also unlikely it should return a refernece to `Iterator`. I would expect it to return a reference to `node` in this case. Note that it is idiomatic to allow mutable access to the data via `const` operators, and to provide a `ConstIterator` type that only allows `const` access):

```
class Iterator 
{
public:
 node& operator*() const;
 node* operator->() const;
private:
  node* pntr;
};

node& Iterator::operator*() const {
  return *pntr;
}
node* Iterator::operator->() const { return pntr; }

node& Iterator::operator*() {
  return *pntr;
}
```

Comment: Does that actually `dereference` the underlying pointer or just simply 'dereference' the class type and return the raw pointer underneath? And is that what the OP wants? .. Should probably note they may also want to overload `operator->()`

Comment: @txtechhelp I had copied OP's implementation, but you're right, one has to de-reference the pointer. Edited.

Comment: @uanchopanza thanks for helping me out. So I now I get `non-const lvalue reference to type 'Iterator'` not sure if this is related to the same question I posted about?

Comment: @txtechhelp I was looking at the operator for `->()` so i think I need to use that as well.

Comment: @juanchopanza does it matter that that the pntr is a node struct? because if I do `cout << *temp;` I get `invalid operands to binary expression`

Comment: @MrPilot I added `operator->`. As for the `cout`, you need to overload the relevant `ostream` operator for the `node` type.

Comment: @juanchopanza great I can do that, and thanks again for the help.

Comment: Technically, there's also out-of-class `operator*` that *does* take a parameter.